# use addjavascriptnterface for webview in ionic4 to use native code

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, webview, ionic4

I can use addJavascriptInterface in plain Html and js to communicate native java code on android (say for displaying a Toast).
But I can't use this in Ionic and typescript.

here is my mainActivity:

```
package io.ionic.starter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", 
false)) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
    WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

 }
 public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
     // Show Toast Message
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
 }
```

this is my home.ts in Ionic4:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var Android:any;
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
showToast(){
alert("show alert");
Android.showToast('Toast made by Javascript');
}
}
```

and the html part:

```
<ion-button (click)="showToast()">show toast</ion-button>
```

and the error when I debug it is :

```
ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 13, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

someone help me please. i have spent 2 days on getting access from webview to java code without luck!